# How it is possible to use filters in Phalcon\Http\Request

Tags: php, phalcon

On the following page is said that it is possible to use filters for Request::getQuery() method:
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Http_Request.html

But unfortunately i was not able to find information about how i am able to setup them.
Could please you assist? I need to filter only number value here:

```
// $filter = ??
$offset = $this->request->getQuery('offset', $filter);
```

In docs it's said that values could be string or an array, where it is possible to see available filters list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this

In a controller by directly applying the filter in the `getQuery` or `getPost`

```
$offset = $this->request->getQuery('offset', 'int');
```

or by calling the `sanitize` function of the filter you want (even custom filters)

```
$filter = new \Phalcon\Filter();

$offset = $filter->sanitize($_GET["offset"], "int");

// or
$offset = $filter->sanitize($request->getQuery("offset"), "int");

// or
$offset = $request->getQuery("offset", "int");
```

and you can also set a default value if the parameter passed is null (4 is the default value below)

```
$offset = $request->getQuery('offset', 'int', 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found this page:

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/0.7.0/reference/filter.html

Answer was pretty simple: no regexps, just string "int"